# Conversion of TF2 model (saved_model.pb) to TF1 format (frozen_inference_graph.pb)

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

Currently OpenCV does not support TF2 Object Detection models. I would like to convert a MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640 SSD model from TF2 to TF1 to run via `cv2.readNetFromTensorflow`. How is this possible to do?

I tried to freeze the neural network graph:

```
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
            tf.TensorSpec(
                model.signatures['serving_default'].inputs[0].shape, 
                model.signatures['serving_default'].inputs[0].dtype)
)

frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(
        full_model
)
```

and received the files:

[image]

Trying to run a model:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(model, config)
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cropped_img, scalefactor = 1.0, size = (640, 640), mean = (0, 0, 0), swapRB = True)
        
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
```

got error:

```
---> 15 detections = net.forward()
     17 for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
     18     confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\bld\libopencv_1654292817370\work\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:4481: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::Net::forward'
```